# Langchain ChatPromptTemplate Template Message (AIMessagePromptTemplate) not defined

Tags: langchain

I'm trying to create a template as follows with mixed message formats, which the official documentation allowed:

```py
 template = ChatPromptTemplate.from_messages([
    ("ai", "I'm doing well, thanks!"),
    AIMessagePromptTemplate.from_template("")
    ])
```

However it keeps returning an error `NameError: name 'AIMessagePromptTemplate' is not defined`.

I checked the [official documentation](https://api.python.langchain.com/en/stable/prompts/langchain_core.prompts.chat.ChatPromptTemplate.html) for `langchain_core.prompts.chat.ChatPromptTemplate` and didn't find anything that could explain why the tuple `"ai", "text"` would work but not `AIMessagePromptTemplate.from_template(template)`

```py
        elif message_type in ("ai", "assistant"):
        message = AIMessagePromptTemplate.from_template(template)
```

Would appreciate any clarification! Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am new to langchain and learning now, as per your question I would say you cann't call `AIMessagePromptTemplate.from_template("")` inside `ChatPromptTemplate.from_messages([` because from_template returns the same class not the tuple which you are expecting. If you want to address the AI type here, you can directly use like `("ai", "I'm doing well, thanks!")`.

Comment: have you found any other solution for this ?